# ReactJS: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. Having issues pushing to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

App not behaving correctly when I try signing up along with posting Stripe payment, it will not push the sashboard component
The error I am getting:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
handleStripeSubmit
src/components/sections/SignupForm.js:78

```
  75 | const { id } = paymentMethod;
  
76 | console.log("111111111 and ID_", id);
  
77 | aprops.signup(state, id);

 78 |    aprops.history.push("/dashboard");

     | ^  79 |  
  80 | console.log("3333333333");
  
81 | // setState({ ...state, stripeId: id });
```

My Code (what do youthink is not working?:
someone, please help...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { Link, withRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import SectionHeader from "./partials/SectionHeader";
import Input from "../elements/Input";
import Button from "../elements/Button";
import { signupUser } from "../../redux/actions/user_action";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';


export const history = createHashHistory()

//Checkout Form component-----------------------------------------------=
const StripeForm = (aprops) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        bname: "Busines Name",
        email: "Email address",
        password: "Password",
        name: "Name on Card",
        amount: 0,
        plan: "",
        stripeId: "",
    });
    const {
        className,
        topOuterDivider,
        bottomOuterDivider,
        topDivider,
        bottomDivider,
        hasBgColor,
        invertColor,
        ...props
    } = aprops;

    const outerClasses = classNames(
        "signin section",
        topOuterDivider && "has-top-divider",
        bottomOuterDivider && "has-bottom-divider",
        hasBgColor && "has-bg-color",
        invertColor && "invert-color",
        className
    );

    const innerClasses = classNames(
        "signin-inner section-inner",
        topDivider && "has-top-divider",
        bottomDivider && "has-bottom-divider"
    );

    const sectionHeader = {
        title: "Welcome. We exist to make cybersecurity easier.",
    };

    const handlechangeall = (event) => {
        setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    const handleRadio = (e) => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            amount: Number(e.target.value) * 100,
            plan: e.target.id,
        });
    };

    const handleStripeSubmit = async () => {
        const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        });
        if (!error) {
            console.log("response of stripe payment___", paymentMethod);
            const { id } = paymentMethod;
            console.log("111111111 and ID_", id);
            aprops.signup(state, id);
      aprops.history.push("/dashboard");
    
            console.log("3333333333");
            // setState({ ...state, stripeId: id });
        }
    };

    const handlesubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        handleStripeSubmit();
        //alert( JSON.stringify(this.state));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
    };

    //Stripe hooks-------
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    //=============================

    return (
        <section {...aprops} className={outerClasses}>
            <div className="container">
                <div className={innerClasses}>
                    <SectionHeader
                        tag="h1"
                        data={sectionHeader}
                        className="center-content"
                    />
                    <div className="tiles-wrap">
                        <div className="tiles-item">
                            <div className="tiles-item-inner">
                                <form onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div className="mb-12">
                                            <Input
                                                label="Business name"
                                                type="text"
                                                name="bname"
                                                value={state.bname}
                                                onChange={handlechangeall}
                                                labelHidden
                                                required
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="mb-12">
                                            <Input
                                                type="email"
                                                name="email"
                                                label="Email"
                                                value={state.email}
                                                onChange={handlechangeall}
                                                labelHidden
                                                required
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="mb-12">
                                            <Input
                                                type="password"
                                                name="password"
                                                label="Password"
                                                value={state.password}
                                                onChange={handlechangeall}
                                                labelHidden
                                                required
                                            />
                                        </div>

                                        {/* Stripe Integration */}
                                        <div className="signin-bottom has-top-divider">
                                            <div className="pt-32 text-xs center-content text-color-low">
                                                Select Subscription tier (to select, use up & down arrow
                                                keys):
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        {/* all packages amounts here */}
                                        <div onChange={handleRadio} className="radio">
                                            {console.log("checking plan amount____", state.amount)}
                                            <div>
                                                <label>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        id="default"
                                                        value="49"
                                                        name="plan"
                                                    />
                                                    ($49/month)
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <label>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        id="basic"
                                                        name="plan"
                                                        value="199"
                                                    />
                                                    Basic ($199/month)
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <label>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        id="complete"
                                                        name="plan"
                                                        value="249"
                                                    />
                                                    Complete ($249/month)
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="pt-32 text-xs center-content text-color-low">
                                            Enter Card Details Here!
                                            <div className="mb-12">
                                                <Input
                                                    label="Name on the card"
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="name"
                                                    value={state.name}
                                                    onChange={handlechangeall}
                                                    labelHidden
                                                    required
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div
                                                style={{
                                                    border: "1px solid grey",
                                                    padding: 15,
                                                    backgroundColor: "#cccccc",
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <CardElement />
                                            </div>
                                            {/* <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
                                                    Checkout
                                                </button> */}
                                            <div className="mt-24 mb-32">
                                                <Button type="submit" color="primary" wide>
                                                    Register
                                                </Button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                                <div className="signin-bottom has-top-divider">
                                    <div className="pt-32 text-xs center-content text-color-low">
                                        Already have an account?{" "}
                                        <Link to="/login/" className="func-link">
                                            Login
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

// const SignupForm = () => {
//  return (
//      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
//          <StripeForm />
//      </Elements>
//  );
// };
// SignupForm.propTypes = propTypes;
// SignupForm.defaultProps = defaultProps;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { signup: (data, id) => dispatch(signupUser(data, id)) };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StripeForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `history` prop to `StripeForm` component - it is undefined. what is actually passed is `{ signup: (data, id) => dispatch(signupUser(data, id)) }`.

A possible solution could be:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ history: [] });
```

or assigning `history` some default value:

```
const {
        className,
        topOuterDivider,
        bottomOuterDivider,
        topDivider,
        bottomDivider,
        hasBgColor,
        invertColor,
        history = [],
        ...props
    } = aprops;
```